# How to merge array and object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var data =[{
    "name": "jack",
    "age": 10
  }, {
    "name": "jhon",
    "age": 12
  }];
var obje = {"name":{'data_one':0,'data_two':5},"age":{'data_one':8,'data_two':9}};
```

How can I get the following result from this array and object.

```
 data[{"name":{"data_one":0,"data_two":5,"display_name":"jack"}
    "age":{"data_one":8,"data_two":9,"display_name":10}},
    {"name":{"data_one":0,"data_two":5,"display_name":"jhon"}
    "age":{"data_one":8,"data_two":9,"display_name":12}}]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: data.forEach(function(key,val) {
  var output = {};
  Object.keys(obje).forEach(function(keys){
  obje[keys]['display_name'] = key[keys];
  });
  key[val]=obje;
});

Comment: I dont get the relationship between in and output...

Comment: @ilyasbahriDudak You really should add this to you question. Also reading [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and doing the [tour](/tour) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested approach with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var data = [{ name: "jack", age: 10 }, { name: "jhon", age: 12 }],
    object = { name: { data_one: 0, data_two: 5 }, age: { data_one: 8, data_two: 9 } },
    result = data.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((r, k) =>
        Object.assign(r, {
            [k]: Object.assign({}, object[k], { display_name: o[k] })
        }), {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object is a collection of properties, and a property is an association between a name (or key) and a value.

You can have object like below (remember Key value pair)

```
spices = [{"name":"pasilla", "spiciness":"mild"},
          {"name":"jalapeno", "spiciness":"hot hot hot!"},
          {"name":"habanero", "spiciness":"LAVA HOT!!"}];
```

more details :[Javascript object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score -1):

Just use push that is declared in Array prototype.

```
data.push(obje)
```

Comment: Why does this have an upvote? This isn't even close to answering the OP's question